# Customise save location in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have been asked to evaluate Office 365 for a small charity. The charity requires that all documents are shared across all users. I have set up a SharePoint site. However, when a document is created in Word or Excel, it automatically saves to the user's private OneDrive location. It is possible to copy the file to SharePoint, but I need to eliminate the manual step, as non-computer literate users are liable to forget.

Please advise how to ensure that documents are always saved to SharePoint.

Some sites I have found suggest I can customise the save location from File -> Options or File -> Save -> Add a Place. I have neither Options or Add a Place. Why are these items missing? Is it because I have a trial version?